Rotational dynamics exercise problem
There is an exercise in my physics textbook, in rotational dynamics, which states: "A small homogenous bar AB of length d = 1 m rotates on a horizontal smooth plane with costant angular velocity $\omega = 2 \text{ rad/s}$ around a vertical axis passing through one of its extremes A. In a given moment the constraint breaks and the bar can move freely, determine its motion". 
My idea was to apply the conservation of momentum and angular momentum, and the book also says that is how the solution should be derived. 
By applying the first, if $v_{CM}$ is the initial velocity of the center of mass, whilst $v_f$ is the final one, I get that
$$mv_{CM}=mv_f \qquad \implies \qquad v_{CM} = v_f = \omega \frac{d}{2} = 1 \text{ m/s}$$
Which the book's solutions also state. As for the angular momentum, the initial and final angular momentums should then be
$$L_i = I_i \omega = \frac{1}{3}md^2 \omega \qquad L_f = I_f\omega_f = \frac{1}{12}md^2 \omega_f$$
Since the rotation axis changed between one of the extremes to the center of the object when the constraint was broken, the moment of inertia also changes according to the Huygens-Steiner theorem.
Equating the two, I got that
$$\omega_f = 4 \omega$$
Which is apparently wrong, as the solutions claim that the angular velocity should remain costant and equal to $w = 2 \text{ rad/s}$, which intuitively makes sense.
At the same time, both this answer and mine seem to break the conservation of energy, since if $v_{f} = 1 \text{ m/s}$ and $\omega_f = 2 \text{ rad/s}$ then the difference in kinetic energy is
$$\Delta K=\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2} m v_{CM}^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{12} m d^2 \omega_f^2 \right)}_{K_f} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{3}md^2 \omega^2}_{K_i}= -\frac{1}{12}m$$
Was this potential energy coming from the constraint between the two objects? And if not where does this energy come from? How can I derive the correct result and what's wrong with my understanding of the conservation of angular momentum, since that got me to the wrong answer?

Your sums are wrong as there is no change in the kinetic energy of the system.
The system starts of with a pure rotation about an end.
When the constraint at end $A$ is removed the motion of the bar is as shown in the left diagram.

The left diagram motion can be considered as a translation of the centre of mass of the rod and a rotation about the centre of mass.

I know intuitively that is the answer, it wouldn't make sense for the bar to just stop rotating once the constraint is removed, however I don't understand what is wrong with my calculations, and moreso than to solve the exercise I wanted to know why my calculations yield a wrong result since that could mean I have a wrong theoretical understanding of some of these concepts

@NICOLATROMBINI Angular momentum is relative to an axis.  Your application of the conservation of angular momentum shifted the axis from the end of the rod to the centre of the rod.

But the rotation axis of the bar does in fact change from A to its center, so why wouldn't I have to take that into account in the moment of inertia?
